# Update CentOS but not owncloud

Tags: centos

On my 6.6 CentOS install I have a stable and working owncloud system, with HTTPD configured with ssl, and a couple of other domains and sub domains.

I would like to update my OS cause it has been a while now, but the problem is that I manually update my owncloud setup to 8.1.3 and the packet manager says the current version that will be replaced is 8.0. If I continue with the update I'm pretty sure it will destroy my owncloud. How can I avoid it?

Is there any way to stop packet manager to update the owncloud setup? I would like to have the control on my owncloud. SO if something goes wrong, to know where to look at you know.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is option `--exclude` for `yum`, which allows you to update all packages except the the selected ones. So for your case, it would be something like

```
# yum update --exclude="owncloud*"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jakuje, I really appreciate it. Are your sure that this will not touch my ownclous setup? Cause my vps provider to not offers any snapshots, so if the system gets destroyed, I have to manually rebuild everything, and its a bit of a mess you know.

Comment: certainly you will get asked once more to review what is updated as for every other yum command.